# Is it possible to encode heterogeneous trees of stateful nodes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

Modeling modular, static web components is very easy in Haskell. A view is a document, a component is just a function that returns a view:

```
-- Renders a pretty clock
clock :: Color -> Html
clock color = div ...

-- Renders a list of views prettily 
list :: [Html] -> Html
list elements = div ...

-- A blue clock
blueClock :: Html
blueClock = clock Blue

-- A list with a Blue, a Yellow, and a Red clock
clockList :: Html
clockList = list [
    clock Blue,
    clock Yellow,
    clock Red]
```

The issue with this approach is when you add **local state** to things. For example:

```
-- Added "Time" to clock's type
clock :: Color -> Time -> Html
clock color time = div ...

-- A blue clock now has a local state: its time.
blueClock :: Time -> Clock
blueClock = clock Blue

-- A list of clock must be aware of the local state of each child clock.
clockList :: [Time] -> Html
clockList times = list [
    clock Blue   (times !! 0),
    clock Yellow (times !! 1),
    clock Green  (times !! 2)]
```

A parent node must be aware of the local state of each children, breaking modularization. Instead of pure views, we need a way to encode self-contained components, each of which would define how to deal with its own internal state. For example:

```
type Component state = ... ??? ...

clock :: Color -> Component Time
clock = ...

list :: [Component a] -> Component ()
list = ...

clocks :: Component ()
clocks = list [
    clock Yellow (0, (+ 1)),
    clock Red    (0, (- 1)),
    clock Blue   (0, (+ 2))]

runComponent :: Component a -> IO HtmlNode
```

Notice that:

1. Clock is a component with a local state of type Time. An instance needs an initial state (here, always 0), and a function, `state -> state`, which is called each "tick" to update its local state. Some clocks run backwards, some run in double speed...
2. A `list` is a component without a local state. It just creates some pretty HTML list with many components. It isn't aware of the local states of the internal clocks at all.
3. `runComponent` is responsible for giving life to the final app, which include calling the state of each sub component correctly.

I've tried countless ways of formalizing this intuition with types, but I couldn't find anything satisfactory. Problems include the fact that components can have different types of states, and the fact that "callbacks" (on, for example, pure buttons) must affect the state of the component that contains it. How can such systems be encoded in Haskell's type system?

Comment: Try existential types.

Comment: The problems you describe sound quite similar to the problems solved in the snap server framework by snaplets; which essentially use lenses to run snaplets with their own state. You could consider reading up on how snaplets work to see if their approach will work for you.

Comment: I'm looking for that kind of recommendation, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. If the data inside a list depends on the current time, then the value of the list certainly depends on the time too. In a purely functional setting there's no way to 'hide' that sort of dependency.

Comment: You could "hide" the internal state of something by making it an argument of a function, and passing the state down the tree. For example, `listOfWords = ("lih", \ x -> div [ ("foo", \ x -> div (str x)), ("bar", \ x -> div (str (x+x))), ("biz", \ x -> div (str (x*3)))])`. Here, each component ha an id ("foo", "bar"...) and an internal state `x`. `listOfWords` is not aware of the state of its children. A function `runComponent` would pass down the state environment so that each node receives its own state, based on its id. That'd hide in the sense it'd allow modularization, @BenjaminHodgson.

Comment: The list has a type of `Num n => [(String, n -> Html)]`. The parameter `n` is not hidden, you can see it right there!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson It is modular, which is the point. If I say `widget :: Int -> [(String, Int -> Html)]`, I can create a `list :: [Widget] -> Widget` component which renders an HTML list of stateful widgets inside it (as long as the state is an Int). Without it, how'd you create a widget that is a list of stateful widgets? I can't see any way. You'd have to create a "listOfClocks", a "listOfBottoms", a "listOfGames", etc - a different code for each widget, because the parent needs to manually provide the state. No reuse of code, no modularization.

Comment: The way you describe it sounds like you want to equip each clock in the list with its own timekeeping device and have them update themselves autonomously. This is an imperative way of thinking, not a functional one. The current time in the real world is not a local piece of data - it's as global as they come (it is literally universal!). The information has to come from the outside of your program and make its way inwards, not the other way around.

Comment: This has nothing to do with imperative thinking, I need modularization of stateful web components, @BenjaminHodgson. In the current, "Elm" approach of writing UIs, the parent of a component must record the state of every children. It means that, in a large site, you'll end up with a root model having the state of the innermost innermost buttons. Imagine that: `data MyAppState = { ......................, stateOfThatButtonInsideThatDivInsideThatList :: Bool ............. }`. And that inner button can alter that global state with no sort of isolation. How is **that** functional?

Comment: Ah, I think we are getting to the core of your question: "that inner button can alter that global state with no sort of isolation". It sounds like you really have a problem of _composition_ - you want to be able to take a `Widget CurrentTime` and a `Widget Username` (where `Widget`'s argument denotes "the thing it depends upon") and somehow mash them together into a `Widget (CurrentTime, Username)`. Have I understood you correctly? If so, you're in luck - I wrote a [whole article](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/issue24.pdf) about a very similar problem.

Comment: ... although you may not need all the machinery I built in that article. If the shape of your data is the same as the shape of your hierarchical widgets, you can probably just use [`contramap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.3.3/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html) to change the size of your environment. [Discussion in the Reddit comments on the article](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3hov5w/the_monadreader_miniissue_24_predicates_trees_and/).

Comment: It may be the confusing nature of the question but why should be held time(s) independently ? Why don't define data type of clock with color and `State` monad for time ? Manipulation of list (or array) of clocks then needn't care about internal time states. Wrapping in a typeclass, use GADTs to loose type restrictions as another ideas. Recursive instance to enable operation with arbitrary widget types, like. heterogenous containers.

Comment: I'm just not sure I visualize what you are doing, but it might be the answer (or not)... @joanbm